# run nunit tests with TestCase Attribute from nant

Tags: nunit, nant

i was using this nant task for my nunit tests.

```
<nunit2 failonerror="false">
  <formatter usefile="true"
             outputdir="build"
             type="Xml"
             extension=".xml"/>
  <test>
    <assemblies>
      <include name="Build/*.Tests.dll"/>
    </assemblies>
    <references >
      <include name="Tools/**/*.dll"/>
      <include name="Build/*.dll"/>
    </references>
  </test>
</nunit2>
```

It had the nice benefit that I could use it in multiple projects without changing anything.  The problem is that it seems to be ignoring the `TestCase` and `ExpectectException` attributes on some of my tests causing them to fail.  I've seen the suggestion to use the `exec` task to call nunit-console.exe, but then I have to specify all of the test dll's individually.  Which means I can no longer use it in all of my projects without having to edit it.  I'd all so have to edit it any time I add a test project to one of my solutions.

Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<foreach>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/foreach.html) to run your tests:

```
<foreach item="File" property="test-assembly">
  <in>
    <items>
      <include name="${binaries-dir}/*" />
    </items>
  </in>
  <do>
    <exec program="${nunit.exe}" workingdir="${binaries-dir}"
        managed="true">
      <arg value="/nologo" />
      <arg value="${test-assembly}" />
    </exec>
  </do>
</foreach>
```